# File Not Found issue while using MS Viewer with self signed https url

Tags: https, self-signed

I am using Microsoft Viewer to view word documents, It was working fine before I switched the website from http to self signed https. Any Help?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I moved back the website to http or paid https URL (instead of self signed), the issue got resolved.